# jQuery set value depending on tagName

Tags: jquery

## Original Question

Is there a jQuery method that will check the selection type and set the value appropriately? Example, using .html() or .val().

I have made my own method to do the work for me however am not sure if this is the best way to preform this task.

```
$.fn.data = function(value) {
    if(this.is("input")){
        this.val(value);
    }else if(... other type ...){
        this.val(value);
    }else{
        this.html(value);
    }
};
```

I have also looked at using the tagName attribute. 
    var type = this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase();

**Edit:**

## Benchmarking

For anyone interested I did a little benchmarking between this.tagName; and $(this).is("input"); with 10,000 records.

`this.tagName.toLowerCase();` x 10,000 records = 185 milliseconds

`$(this).is("input");` x 10,000 records = 1676  milliseconds

Comment: I personally recommend `this[0].tagName` as opposed to either of the jQuery methods below. It shouldn't make a difference for small uses, but if you were doing something like this thousands of times, this would be much faster. jsperf: http://jsperf.com/testtagname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go in plugin format:

```
$.fn.setVal = function(value) {

    return this.each(function() {

        if ($.inArray( this.tagName.toLowerCase(), ['input', 'textarea', 'select'] ) != -1) {
            $(this).val( value );
        } else {
            $(this).text( value );
        }       
    });
};
```

Use it as follows:

```
$('input, span').setVal('Some Value');
```

---

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fkHLc/

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest option. I was planning on using adding this as a method on an existing plugin however I can see it being useful as part of the jQuery namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Since `.val` is primarily used for `input` elements, you could write something using the [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

```
if (this.is(":input")) {
   this.val(value);
} else { 
   this.html(value);
}
```

Or if you wanted to be more specific, you could use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
if (this.is("input, textarea, select" /*, etc. */) {
    this.val(value);
} else {
    this.html(value);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks this option works well however after a little benchmarking using tagName inserted of jQuert.is() seems to yield better performance on large pages.

Comment: if your interested I added the benchmarking results to original question.